Increase the width to 100% if content is greater than 50%
Consider the following HTML and CSS, I would like to increase the width of .responsive-list to 100% if the width of the any of the children (content) is greater than 50%. Is it possible to achieve that with css only? or javascript is inevitable in this case.
<body>
    <div class="responsive-list">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3 with a lot of content that might exceed 50</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </div>
</body>

.responsive-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  min-width: 50%;
  width: max-content; /* something like: if max-content > 50% then 100% else 50%  */
}

.responsive-list li {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 5px 0;
}


Not with CSS, no. You need javascript
